# Fullcalendar fc-time with custom color

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, fullcalendar, agenda

I am programming an appoiment calendar for a beauty center. I am using Symfony and fullCalendar in agendaView. I need each event(appointment) to have two colors:
1.-The color of the type of treatment (fc-title background color) and the other 2.-The color that describes if it has a discount or not (border color and fc-time color).

Here is the code of my controller (I have translate it). the calendar automatically adds the backcolor and bordercolor as desired, but I have no idea what I can do to change also fc-time color. Any help

```
public function readAppointmentsAction(Request $request)
{
  $apps = $db->readAppointments();
  foreach ($apps as $app) {
   $color = $db->readColor($app['treatment_id']);
   $bordercolor = $db->readBorderColor($app['type']);
   $app['id'] = $app['id'];
   $app['start'] = $app['start_time'];
   $app['end']   = $end_time;
   $app['title'] = $app['client_name'];
   $app['backgroundColor']= $color;
   $app['borderColor']= $bordercolor;
   $calendarEvents[] = $app;
 }
 return new JsonResponse($calendarEvents);
}
```

EDIT DONE: 
In the controller I added this line:

```
$app['className'] = $bodercolor;
```

and in the css I added:

```
.red .fc-time {
  background-color: red; 
}

.green .fc-time {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) has a `textColor` setting.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I need the textColor to remind white. I have seen that people has achive to put darker color to the fc-time, but I want both custom colors in time and title. here is an example of darker color: http://suren-drummer.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/free-event-calendar-template-screenshot-of-event-calendar-planner-free-annual-calendar-template-2015.jpg

Comment: I am not able to view that page, but if you are, you could probably view the source and see what settings are used.

Comment: It is a jpg. I have been reading this project too, but I can not find where he sets the fc-time color. http://www.whatibroke.com/2012/12/02/fullcalendar-with-client-side-event-updates/

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page with the calendar on it?

Comment: you could handle it manually via the eventRender callback - there you can manipulate the HTML of the  event any way you wish based on the event data. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Comment: Thank yo everyone. I have done it! You can see the answer in the question I just edited